# On hover: higlight all identical links to Wikipedia in one colour, highlight all identical links elswhere in a different color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to highlight all identical links to Wikipedia **blue** on hover, whereas all identical links elsewhere would be higlighted **green** on hover.

The Wikipedia-part, I have managed using the following **jQuery** code:

```js
$(function () {
    function getKey(element) {
        return element.href;}
    function sameGroupAs(element) {
        var key = getKey(element);
        return function () {
            return getKey(this) === key;}}
    $(document)
    .on("mouseenter", "a[href*=wikipedia]", function () {
        $("a").filter(sameGroupAs(this)).addClass("wikipedia");})
    .on("mouseleave", "a", function () {
        $("a").filter(sameGroupAs(this)).removeClass("wikipedia");});});
```

```css
a.wikipedia{background-color: #A8c5ff}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Wikipedia: <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experiential_learning">experiential learning</a>. And all <b>identical</b> links get higlighted at the same time. E.g.: the next occurence <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experiential_learning">experiential learning</a> gets highlighted simultaneously.
```

As for the **green higlight on hover for non-Wikipedia-pages**, I am still struggling.

## What I've tried so far:

You might have a good laugh, since I am under-experienced, but I'll try to show where I got stuck:

I tried to duplicate the code again, to now specify an extra condition... E.g., trying to use the [jQuery `:not()`-selector](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/)
For example, checking to see if the negation of the Wikipedia-class applies,

- `$( "a[href]:not(:contains('wikipedia'))" ).css( "color", "green" );`

or I have tried things similar to:

- `"a:not([href*=wikipedia])"`...

Or by adding an `if`Wikipedia?->{nothing}`else`{green}-statement.

- `if(!$(this).hasClass("wikipedia")){;`*nothing*`}` `else{addClass("green");}`

Another option I have tried (also without success, since the Wikipedia-part then gets overruled, whereas I would like just to let the Wikipedia-part prioritize):

- Copy the code, and replace `"a[href*=wikipedia]"` by `"a"` and add a class for green. Then, the desired result would be achieved if only the Wikipedia-part could impose itself over the general `"a"`'s.

Any help would be greatly appreciated (from this beginner, as you can notice).

Comment: something like this http://jsfiddle.net/k1drpjr0/1/

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes I think he wants *all* related links to highlight on hover, not just the current active element.

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes - That's the idea, however would it be possible to have all ***identical** links* higlighted at the same time? I have adjusted my snippet above, to clarify the desired result. --- @ mattytommo: Yes, exactly, that would be desired. it is now clarified in the Wikipedia-part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with a combination of CSS attribute selectors and re-using your existing functions, but making them more generic.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vwx8fcyw/1/)

JavaScript:

```
function getKey(element) {
   return element.href;
}

function sameGroupAs(element) {
    var key = getKey(element);
    return function () {
        return getKey(this) === key;
    }
}

$(document).on("mouseenter", "a", function () {
    $("a").filter(sameGroupAs(this)).addClass("active");
}).on("mouseleave", "a", function () {
    $("a").filter(sameGroupAs(this)).removeClass("active");
});
```

Then the CSS:

```
a[href*="wikipedia"].active {
   background:red;
}

a:not([href*="wikipedia"]).active {
   background:green;
}
```

Comment: That's just great! Thanks a lot! I hadn't figured out it would be possible to move the jQuery's `*=` to the *CSS*. I can further learn from your help. So, [Vitorino Fernandes](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4025556/vitorino-fernandes)'s quick comment was on the good track.

Comment: @VincentVerheyen Hehe yeah, most of jQuery's selectors map to CSS ones. Some are CSS3 only though, so always best to check if you're having to support older browsers :).